# Override postinst scriptlet to not start service and register it

Tags: sbt, sbt-native-packager

I'm using SBT native packager 1.2.0-M3 for packaging a Play Framework 2.5.3 application as an RPM (targeted for RHEL 7 with systemd). I would like to change the behavior of the generated RPM such that it does NOT automatically start after install but is being enabled (`systemctl enable <name>.service`).

I've been following the instructions outlined at http://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/archetypes/java_server/customize.html. Specifically, I created a file `src/rpm/scriptlets/post-rpm` containing a single line `systemctl enable <name>.service`. As far as I understand the documentation, that's all that is required. However, on installation of the RPM the service gets still automatically started. Is there any additional configuration required?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is currently the default behaviour. There is a historical explanation [here](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-native-packager/issues/812).

What you actually need to do are the `maintainerScripts in Rpm`.
There is [a helper trait](http://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/latest/api/#com.typesafe.sbt.packager.archetypes.MaintainerScriptHelper) which lightens the build definition. Something like

```
 import RpmConstants._
 maintainerScripts in Rpm := {
     (maintainerScripts in Rpm).value += (
         Post -> "systemctl enable <name>.service"
      )
 }
```

And there is a [feature request](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-native-packager/issues/807) to implement this in native-packager directly.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I will change the answer accordingly. Don't quite understand why it was rejected